# How to sort my datagrid table

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I fill datagrid from DataBase using sqlite - ShowDataBase(string a);

Then I want to sort It,When Button is Clicked
(Note! I want to sort it only in program(not modding the DB). Just want to delete wrong rows)

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowDataBase("Pacients");

        if ((bool)SortFromCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Delete all data earlier than data that user asked for
            for (int i = DataGridMain.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGridMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                var item = DataGridMain.Items[i];
                var data = DataGridMain.Columns[4].GetCellContent(item);
                if ((Convert.ToDateTime(data)) <= (Convert.ToDateTime(SortFromTextBox.Text)))
                {
                    //Smth to delete row № i from datagrid

                }
            }
        }
        if ((bool)SortUntilCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Delete all data older than data that user asked for
        }
        if ((bool)SortByClientCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Delete all data where client cell is != name that user want to sort by
        }
        if ((bool)SortByDoctorCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Delete all data where doctor cell is != name that user want to sort by
        }
    }
```

Comment: take the data from database again, filter it and bind it again, any specific reason you want to delete data's from datagridrow?

Comment: Cant i just delete or hide my row in datagrid, without connecting to database?I actually have no such qualification to do, what you offer me to do... :(

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need a functionality to filter and sort the data. You could make use of a build in mechanics for that purpose: `CollectionView`. You need to create one which source will be set to the data you get from database.

To filter the collection you can use the `collectionView.Filter` and define different filters for your purposes. For Sorting functionality you should make use of `collectionView.SortDescriptions`. This way you utilize the tools already present in .NET that you only need to customize for your needs.

With this approach, you don't remove anything from base collection, so you need to get the data only once and present it in different ways in your application. If you are using MVVM approach, this code should be done in the ViewModel. If you insist on achieving such functionality in your View, you could play with `<CollectionViewSource>`.

You can find some resources here:

- [Dr.WPF: ItemsControl: 'C' is for Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/05/itemscontrol-c-is-for-collection/)
- [Dr.WPF: ItemsControl: 'E' is for Editable Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/)
- [MSDN: How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looks Like Realy helpfull, I gonna chech it, thank you

Comment: @SergeyOksky If this helped you with your problem, please mark it as an answer.